# How does a method use parameters that aren't in the header of the method?

Tags: java

That's probably not the best way to phrase that question, but this program is confusing me quite a bit:

```
 public class MysterySoda {

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String soda = "coke";
    String pop = "pepsi";
    String coke = "pop";
    String pepsi = "soda";
    String say = pop; 
    carbonated(coke, soda, pop);
    carbonated(pop, pepsi, pepsi);
    carbonated("pop", pop, "koolaid");
    carbonated(say, "say", pop);   
  }

  public static void carbonated(String coke, String soda, String pop) {
    System.out.println("say " + soda + " not " + pop + " or " + coke);    
  }
}
```

From the line:

```
carbonated(pop, pepsi, pepsi);
```

the output is:

```
say soda not soda or pepsi
```

Could someone please explain how the the program is interpreted to choose soda, soda, and pepsi as the outputs?
I feel that the output should be:

```
say pepsi not soda or soda
```

because that is what those variables are equal to.

Thank you.

Comment: The variable names and the strings they contain are simply confusing (as is the way the method prints them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable name is not related to its content. Since you call

```
carbonated(pop, pepsi, pepsi);
```

and

- `pop = "pepsi"`
- `pepsi = "soda"`

it is like calling

```
carbonated("pepsi", "soda", "soda");
```

Those strings are passed to method arguments

```
carbonated(String coke, String soda, String pop)
```

which means that inside `carbonated` methods body those arguments hold:

- `coke` -> `"pepsi"`
- `soda` -> `"soda"`
- `pop` -> `"soda"`

which means (notice they are used in different order than their declaration)

```
System.out.println("say " + soda + " not " + pop + " or " + coke); 
//                           ↑                ↑               ↑
//                         "soda"           "soda"         "pepsi"
```

resulting in `say soda not soda or pepsi`